# How to Insert OneDrive Excel file into OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-onenote-2013

Excel File is stored into OneDrive. I want to Insert it into OneNote such that if I update Excel file outside, the changes appear in OneNote and vice versa.

I don't want to Insert copy of that excel file, but I want to Insert that same file (like pass by reference).

Comment: Do you mean inserting a link of the file into OneNote?

Comment: @Mate It needs to be embedded, but it shouldn't be copy...